# how can get subscription level resources Or how can set subscription level permission using ARM Templates.?

Tags: azure-rm-template, azure-marketplace

**I have used RBACK to set permission, but its not working.**

```
"resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
      "name": "[variables('roleName')]",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('authAPIVersion')]",
      "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635')]",
        "principalId": "[parameters('principalId')]",
        "scope": "[subscription().id]"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

role assignment do work, as far as I remember. but generally speaking, subscription level resources should not work.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
            "name": "8446a13c-6886-46e2-a17f-9df73adb334e",
            "apiVersion": "2017-10-01-preview",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "roleDefinitionId": "[concat(subscription().Id, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c')]",
                "principalId": "user_guid_goes_here",
                "scope": "[resourceGroup().Id]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```